# ImageView with LayoutParams match_parent doesn't match parent when parent size changes at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have an imageview that I want to fill it's parent RelativeLayout to act as a background image.

The image is the correct size until the other views in the relative layout expand, and thus expand the size of the entire layout (just height in my case) (ie: a large string from the internet has been loaded into a textView). Then the image view doesn't grow to continue matching the parent. Is that expected behavior and if so, how do we get around it?

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/parentLayout">
<my.BlurredImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/profile_bg"
    ImageUrl= "Avatar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
 />
 <LOTS AND LOTS OF OTHER VIEWS>
```

Comment: how do you know that " image view doesn't grow "?

Comment: At first I guessed it didnt because the image only covered 3/4 of the relative layout after items were added. Then I looked at it in Android Monitor Layout View, and saw the bounds of the object

Answer (score 0):

OK I am sure you know this already, but for thoroughness I thought I should mention that the easiest way to set the background of the relative layout is directly in the background field:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="drawable file or file from internet you load programatically"
    android:id="@+id/parentLayout">
```

Now to your question. If for whatever reason you really need an imageView as a background, then use the width and height as 0dp because you are aligning to parent on all 4 sides. See if this makes a difference:

```
<my.BlurredImageView
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:id="@+id/profile_bg"
    ImageUrl= "Avatar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
```

To check the actual size of the image view, and whether it fills your relative layout, the most practical way would be to make the background of the RelativeLayout bright green, and the background of the imageView bright Orange. Then you always know exactly where they are :-)